# C++ push_back overwrites last vector element

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Since I cannot answer my own question in 8 hours after asking, I'm posting my solution here.

Made some mistakes in the incoming channel number and number of the vector element. Setting the value of channel-1 instead of channel fixed to problem.

My new function is as follows:

```
void input(long inlet, t_symbol *s, long ac, t_atom *av){
    // GET VARIABLES
    long channel = atom_getlong(av);
    double value = atom_getfloat(av + 1);
    long v_size = v_chan.size();
    if(channel && v_size < channel){
        for(int i = v_size; i < channel; i++){
            v_chan.push_back(n_chan);
        }
        v_chan[channel - 1].value = value;
    }
    else if(channel){
        v_chan[channel - 1].value = value;
    }
}
```

---

I've got a vector containing structs, which I like to push_back with a new, empty struct.
Example code:

```
struct channels{
  double value;
  // eventually more variables
};

vector<channels> v_chan;
channels n_chan;

void push(){
  v_chan.push_back(n_chan);
}
```

The problem is, if my vector contains elements, push_back add an element, but also overwrites the last element.

For example, if my vector size is 1 and element 0 has a value of 0.2, after push_back my vector size is 2, but element 0 and 1 have a value of 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

Real Code: (MAX/MSP external, function input is called in Max)

```
#include <maxcpp6.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct bind{
    string param;
    double* value;
    int track;
    double base;
    double multiplier;
};

struct channels{
    double value;
    vector<int> bind;
};

vector<channels> v_chan;
vector<bind> v_bind(19);
channels n_chan;

class rec : public MaxCpp6<rec> {
public:
rec(t_symbol * sym, long ac, t_atom * av) {
    setupIO(1, 1); // inlets / outlets
}
~rec() {}

// methods:


//SET BIND FUNCTION
void setBind(long inlet, t_symbol *s, long ac, t_atom *av){
}

void output(long track, long type){

}

void input(long inlet, t_symbol *s, long ac, t_atom *av){
    // GET VARIABLES
    long channel = atom_getlong(av);
    double value = atom_getfloat(av + 1);
    long v_size = v_chan.size();
    if(v_size <= channel){
        v_chan.push_back(n_chan);
    }
    else{
        v_chan[channel].value = value;
    }
}

void dump(long inlet){
    for(int i = 1; i <= v_chan.size(); i++){
        post("%d %.2f", i, v_chan[i].value);
    }
}

    void clearTrackBinds(long inlet){

    }

    void reset(long inlet){
        clearTrackBinds(0);
    }
};

C74_EXPORT int main(void) {
    // create a class with the given name:
    rec::makeMaxClass("solar_receiver");
    REGISTER_METHOD_GIMME(rec, input);
    REGISTER_METHOD_GIMME(rec, setBind);
    REGISTER_METHOD(rec, dump);
    REGISTER_METHOD(rec, clearTrackBinds);
    REGISTER_METHOD(rec, reset);
}
```

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that you are not showing us the real code. Create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Added, but it's not self contained since the code is for a Max external. The variables channel and value are received from Max, main function only registers the other functions so Max can use them.

Comment: Without a self-contained example, we can't see what else is going on! As Daniel stated: you'll need to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)!

Comment: The real code is now a direct copy-paste. I can't provide anything else because it's for a Max external. You can compile it, but you'll be unable to run it except if you have Max/MSP.

Comment: @user2899919 Instead of direct copy-paste, you are allowed to write *different* code which reproduces the problem. That is typically what a SSCCE is: "I encountered a problem in my big complex code base which I cannot show you - so I wrote a small test program which exhibits the same problem, and which I *can* show"

Comment: Ok, I understand. I wrote some code which did not reproduce the problem.. However, I managed to fix the problem!